# Open modal pop up when clicking on background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to upload image using browse button,browse should be overlay at the bottom of image preview.i want to show file choose prompt when clicking browse overlay and   also show modal pop up when clicking the image preview.I am facing an issue as modal pop up opens when clicking the browse button.

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code instead of a thumbnail you want to click

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
$( '#browseImg' ).click(function(){
    $( '#fileInput' ).click(); 
});
```

Add an `id` named 'browseImg' in the image, then an `id` name 'fileInput' in the button. If this is correct, when you click the image, the script will click the button instead